# Creating a hybrid CD with Audio tracks + PC Windows application + Mac OS X application

Tags: windows, macos, compact-disc, autorun, hybrid-disk

I'm looking to create a hybrid CD with standard "red book" CD-Audio tracks (to be played in regular CD players) but also containing an application with two versions, for Windows and Mac OS X.

I'm not sure if Mac OS X CDs must still use the HFS filesystem (as in old 90s Macs) or just the regular ISO9660. Do I really need to include two partitions in the data part of my CD? (HFS for Mac and ISO9660 for Windows). In that case, what program can I use to achieve this? (while also having CD-Audio tracks in the disc).

Am I better off just including both versions (Mac and Windows) in the same ISO9660 partition? In that case I guess I could just use Nero to create a standard multisession CD with audio tracks and a single ISO9660 partition.

Also, how do I make the CD automatically run the Mac application in a modern Mac OS X, and the Windows application in the PC? I know Mac OS X doesn't support autorun, but I think I can still set which app will be opened when double clicking the CD volume, can't I? In Windows, CDs don't autorun anymore, either, but I guess adding "action" to the autorun.inf file will at least make it appear in the autoplay dialog.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Roxio Toast used to be good for that, though I haven't looked at it in quite some time, because Macs don't have optical drives any more. You cannot make a Mac autorun an app on an external drive, btw, nor should you try to actually run an app from an optical drive; you should at least get the user to manually copy it to the internal HD, preferably to the Applications folder.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Toast is an OSX only app, isn't it? I need one for Windows since my Mac Mini doesn't have a CD drive as well :). Anyway, I guess I can create a regular ISO9660 CD and OSX should read it, though it'd be nice to have a confirmation. About running the app directly from the CD, why shouldn't I do it? I want to run the app from the CD because it's just a an extra for a music CD, so people won't want to go and install it just for that.

Comment: OS X can read ISO9660 - the difficulty would be getting windows to write HFS, for which you'd need something like [these recommendations](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-read-mac-formatted-drive-windows/) Running it from the CD would just be terminally slow

Comment: But if OS X can read ISO9660 there's no need for HFS in the CD, is there? About reading from CD, it's a relatively small app so I don't think it can be that bad. But if there's a performance problem, maybe I could put the whole thing into a self-extracting executable RAR archive. So the question would still be how do I make something run from the CD when double clicking in the CD volume? (be it the actual app or the self-extracting app)

Comment: It's been too long since I ever tried using that type of CD, I just don't remember - it's the kind of thing I was doing in the 90s but really haven't done much with opticals in years. This might help - http://www.macdisk.com/isomacen.php

Comment: It would help if that article had a date, because I don't know how old can this be. When it talks  about "Macintosh", does it mean old Mac systems or Mac OS X? I'm only interested in supporting the latter. Anyway, if OSX still has such a poor support of ISO9660, I might consider sticking to 8+3 filenames, but it would be better to know for sure if I really have to.